# Ionic adding pages

Tags: ionic-framework, mobile

I just started using the ionic-framework and I know that with jQueryMobile you need to add the pages inside the same html with a page id and link to it.

But how do multiple pages work with the Ionic Framework?

On this example:

http://codepen.io/ionic/pen/AjgEB

I see that they use

```
 <script id="file.html" type="text/ng-template">
```

Am I supposed to do it that way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Normally, one adds the pages in separate files.
The above notation is just used for codepens or similar sites, where you can not add additional files into your online code.

You should take a look at an ionic starter app. Create one by writing

```
ionic start myApp
```

into your console.

Answer (score 0):

This may be old post, but i created a tool with ability to generate ionic seed apps with all required pages. For ex., if you need a profile page for your app, using this tool, you can specify pages you need and it will generate the app with all necessary files and references in index.html.

Link for the tool: 
http://ionic-sarav.rhcloud.com/#/ionicbuilder/home